# One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values. Where are the issues?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, metadata, aar

I am getting the infamous "One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:" error in AndroidStudio. Nothing special! The only surprising thing is that it comes when I try to build  just the empty project created by AndroidStudio itself (the one that prints just Hello world)!

My question is: where are those issues listed? There is of course no "message" window (though a balloon popup asks me to look there). The "build" window merely says "One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:" with nothing after the colon.

Again, my question NOT about how to correct the issues. I want to know where the issues are listed.

In case this helps: I can compile other projects successfully. My minSdk is 21, targetSdk is 32. The same specs are used in both the empty project (that won't build) and the earlier ones that do build successfully.

I tried playing with the gradle script file. But in vain.

Edit: I notice that the problem goes away if I build in  release mode. But still I want to know what is going wrong in  debug mode. I am using ubuntu 20.04.3. My AndroidStudio version is Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3